# How should I directly refer to works using the Harvard style?

Tags: citations, citation-style

I am not clear how a work should be cited *directly* in text using the Harvard style (specifically, the Harvard Bath variety). This is probably best explained through examples. Consider the alternatives:

- In (Smith, 2000), the author explains that ...
- In Smith (2000), the author explains that ...
- In *Article Name Goes Here* (Smith, 2000), the author explains that ... (I want to avoid this very verbose although clear format, ideally.)
- some other format

What's the correct way to do this?

I'd also be curious how the above applies when specific sections are cited, for example.

Answer (score 1):

If you are strictly adhering to Harvard style your third verbose example would be used, and this is what I suggest to my students in writing dissertations. It is better to be clear and in this way it is also obvious that it is a citation by using the same style at every place in the corpus.

Other formats just appear if the writer was lazy; but others may have different opinions.

Comment: Thank you. It certainly is the clearest. My concern is mainly when article names happen to be long, in which case it becomes unwieldy. For articles, books, etc. with titles and subtitles, the tile alone can be used in such cases, perhaps.